# In Javascript, how can i execute a function that returns an object and append that object to a different js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a huge object map required for my application to load some files, but i want to automate it by creating a function.Then i dont want to call this function everytime as it adds latency. so i want to execute this function before hand generate the required object and append the same?

for example I have a function like:

```
const config = function(configuration) {
....
returns { Object_MapA = ObjectMapA,
ObjectMapB = ObjectMapB}
}
// I want o get the below Object maps and append them to a the file 
// instead of calling the above function everytime
ObjectMapA = {
a: {metadata:{},
    color:[],
     ...},
b: {metadata:{},
    color:[],
    ...}
}
ObjectMapB = {
    C: {metadata:{},
        color:[],
         ...},
    D: {metadata:{},
        color:[],
        ...}
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what do you mean by Object map?

Comment: added more info

Comment: What do you mean by "append to a file"? No, all you do is to build the object in memory, store it in a variable, and access that single object later. This has nothing to do with the files in which the code is located.

Comment: Why not just create a json file and then require it?